# Wordpress blog pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a posts loop in `home.php`:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 2
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
```

How can I add pagination (numbers)? I looked for a tutorial. I tried a lot of functions but none worked.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible using this code:

```
 <?php the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size' => 2 ) ); ?>
```

`mid_size` defines how many page numbers will be displayed on either side of the current page in that line.

For more details including individual texts for the previous/next page links see:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination

Comment: How can I remove (or change) 'page' in url? www.website.com/blog/page/2/

Comment: AFAIK you can't - that's part of WP'S pagination function. But what's bad about it?

Comment: When page is not in english it looks bad, I think. But maybe you're right.

Comment: To be honest: I think "normal" users hardly ever look at the URL of a subpage